# Executar uma função 100 milisegundos depois que uma animação começar

Tags: jquery

Tenho a função que muda a opacidade de vários elementos com a classe `.single-product` para `1`. Meu problema é que sempre que a página carrega, essa função vai executar uma animação por 500 milisegundos e depois disso ela executa a mesma função novamente para que todos os elementos tenham um pequeno fade quando a página carrega. Como fazer um delay menor entre essas animações?

```
var children = [];
$("#prod-general").children().each(function() {
    children.push(this);
});

function fadeThemOut(children) {
    if (children.length > 0) {
        var currentChild = children.shift();
        $(currentChild).set.animate({
            'opacity': '1'},
            500, function() {
                fadeThemOut(children);
        });
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r5bqatpz/2/)

Comment: A resolução do problema resolvido em: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611168/run-callback-function-in-the-middle-of-an-animation-instead-of-the-end?noredirect=1#comment40009048_25611168

Comment: Oi, Caio, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Você pode publicar sua própria resposta, assim ficamos com o registro da solução do problema aqui também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minha sugestão é:

```
$("#prod-general > *").each(function (i, el) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(el).animate({'opacity': '1'}, 500);
    }, i * 100)
});
```

Assim percorre todos os descendentes diretos de `#prod-general` e usa o index que o método passa como agrumento e multiplica por 100 milisegundos. Na prática cada elemento começa a animação 100 milisegundos depois do anterior.

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/e6dxb5ef/